# Qt doesn't write anything to Arduino until function on_pushButton_pressed has ended

Tags: qt, csv, arduino, serial-port, buffer

I want to read a list of character from a csv file and then send that list to an Arduino through the Serial port with some delay in between each value.
If I send isolated data, the arduino receive it. I can check the reception by blinking the built-in LED. (turn it on if '1' is received, off if '0' is received)
But when I send the whole list with :

```
for (int i =0; i < data.length(); i ++) {
    arduino->write(data[i]);
    Sleep(100);
}
```

The Arduino only take into account the last piece of infromation received.
I think Qt don't send anything through the serial port until the loop is finished and then it send all the data at once (ignoring the `Sleep(100);`) thus all the information but the last is skipped.
I think that Qt store the information temporarily in a buffer and I tried to flush the buffer every time I write something by adding `arduino->flush();` in the loop.
The arduino still received all the information at the end of the loop and not progressively.
I tried to put arduino->flush in a loop to make sure the whole buffer has been sent with :

```
while(arduino->flush() == true) {}
```

but this cause an infinite loop.

Here's the Qt code below:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QStringList wordList;
     QFile f("file.csv");

     if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
     {
     //file opened successfully

        QString stringData;
        char readData[200];
        while (f.readLine(readData, 200)>0)
        {
            Sleep(50);
            stringData = QString(readData);
            wordList = stringData.split(';');
            if (wordList.length()==6)
            {
                data.append(QString("%1\n").arg(wordList[0]));
            }
        }
        f.close();
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i ++)
        {
            commuSerial(data[i]);
            Sleep(500);
        }

     }

}
void MainWindow::commuSerial(QString data)
{
   arduino->write(data.toStdString().c_str());
   arduino->flush();
}
```

Here's the Arduino code (though I am pretty sure there isn't any error in this one)

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        int data= Serial.parseInt();
        digitalWrite(13, data);
    }
}
```